# Is it possible to pass v-for props to a component slotted in the html? Slot props aren't working

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I would like to pass the "instance" property of the v-for loop to the slot, and use it in a component added to that slot in the html.

**List Component**

```
<template>
  <two-col-row-display
    :field="field"
    :fieldcss="fieldcss"
    :valuecss="valuecss"
  >
    <component
      :is="listType"
    >
      <li v-for="instance, i in map_instances(instances)" :key="map_id(instance)">
          <slot name="default" :instance="instance">{{ map_display(instance) }}</slot>
      </li>
    </component>
  </two-col-row-display>
</template>
```

**Slotted Component**

```
<template v-slot:default="liProps">
  <div class="vue_wrap">
    {{ liProps.instance.description }}
  </div>
</template>
```

**HTML**

```
<display-list
    field="Display Ingredient"
    :map_id="instance => instance.ingredient_id"
    :map_instances="instances => {{ $recipe->ingredients }}"
>
    <display-ingredient></display-ingredient>
</display-list>
```

The "instance" property is not passed via "liProps" to the component.  I get a "prop not defined" error whether I declare it as a prop or not.  If create a new component and pass in both the display list and the slotted component the desired result is achieved, but this is less flexible.  I would prefer to find a way to access the v-for loop data in the component as slotted into the html.

**Works, but not desirable for reusability**

```
<template>
  <display-list
    :field="field"
    :fieldcss="fieldcss"
    :list-type="listType"
    :map_id="map_id"
    :map_instances="map_instances"
    :valuecss="valuecss"
  >
    <template v-slot:default="liProps">
      {{liProps.instance.description}}
    </template>
  </display-list>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<display-list>
    <display-ingredient></display-ingredient>
</display-list>
```

In the above (simplified) template, you aren't passing any props nor slots to `<display-ingredient>`; it won't magically receive this data just because you slotted it inside `<display-list>`.

You should make `<display-ingredient>` receive an `instance` prop. It doesn't need a slot since it just has to render `instance`:

```html
<template>
  <div class="vue_wrap">
    {{ instance.description }}
  </div>
</template>
```

Now you have to hook together the components: pass `instance` to `<display-ingredient>`. `instance` is passed to the default slot of `<display-list>`, so you can just use `v-slot` [shorthand syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Abbreviated-Syntax-for-Lone-Default-Slots) for the special case when the component only has one slot which is `default`:

```html
<display-list v-slot="{ instance }">
    <display-ingredient :instance="instance"></display-ingredient>
</display-list>
```

Comment: hmm, that does work, but I would prefer to not have to add that in the html each time it is used, rather having it once in the component, since it is static.  I had assumed that the slot prop would be passed to the slotted item.  I

Answer (score 0):

After a lot more research and experimentation I found that substituting a  for the  and using dynamic components

**DisplayListDynamic**

```
<template>
  <two-col-row-display
    :field="field"
    :fieldcss="fieldcss"
    :valuecss="valuecss"
  >
    <component :is="listType">
      <li v-for="instance, i in map_instances(instances)" :key="map_id(instance)">
          <component :is="display || 'div'" :instance="display ? instance : undefined" class="vue_wrap">
            {{ map_display(instance) }}
          </component>
      </li>
    </component>
  </two-col-row-display>
</template>

...

props: {
   display: { //name of the component, if provided
      type: String,
   },
   map_display: {
      type: Function,
      default: () => '-', // This keeps from an error when the slot default isn't used
   },
...
```

The `:is="display || 'div'"` changes the component to the Vue component set in display.  If it is not set, it becomes a div when rendered.

The `:instance="display ? instance : undefined"` sets the instance prop of the component to "instance" only if display is set, otherwise it is undefined and does not render in the view.  This prevents `instance=[object object]` from appearing in the rendered html if the default div is being used.

`{{ map_display(instance) }}` is the default value, if the display prop is not declared.

if map_display is not declared, `default: () => '-'` the prop defaults to showing a character

**DisplayIngredient**

```
<template>
  <div>
    {{ instance.description }}
  </div>
</template>

...

props: {
          instance: {
            type: Object,
            required: true,
          },
        },
```

The instance prop is declared and required in the component that can be swapped in

**html**

```
  <display-list-dynamic
    field="Ingredients Dynamic"
    :map_display="instance => instance.line"
    :map_id="instance => instance.ingredient_id"
    :map_instances="instances => {{ $recipe->ingredients }}"
  ></display-list-dynamic>
  <display-list-dynamic
    field="Ingredients Dynamic Switch"
    display="display-ingredient"
    :map_id="instance => instance.ingredient_id"
    :map_instances="instances => {{ $recipe->ingredients }}"
  ></display-list-dynamic>
```

In the first example, the display prop is not declared. `:map_display="instance => instance.line"` a default value would be rendered if the map_display prop is not defined. In the second example the display prop is declared `display="display-ingredient"` and thus the component becomes the "display-ingredient" Vue component.